# How to enforce Perl create unsigned integer overflows without warnings, e.g. that $a+$b is simply calculated as ($a+$b) modulo 2**64?

Tags: perl, unsigned-integer

In creating hash functions and larger number arithmetics, it is useful to simply care about the least significant bits and not worry about overflows. I'd need these variables to be treated as unsigned 64-bit variables (machine word architecture) and am expecting correct values `$a*$b` or `$a+$b` only in their "least significant 64 bits". In C it would simply be the case, but Perl starts warning of over Infinity, or possibly creates negative values (use integer).

I do not need high precision (BigInt), only the least significant digits, all 64 of them.

(wanted to generate Fibonacci numbers modulo 2**64)

Comment: You could use the [128 bits](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Int128) module, and `&` the result with `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`

Comment: Perl automatically promotes integers to floats. Native numbers are therefore not the right tool. I don't know if PDL can help. Maybe unsigned ints from Math::Int64 would do the trick.But maybe best to just use C (via Inline::C or FFI:: Platypus)?

Comment: Doesn't 'use integer' do what you want? It makes most of the arithmetic operators within its scope act like C-level integer ops (except ++, looking now).

Comment: @Dave Mitchell, The OP said it causes the production of negative values

Comment: raku -e "say ( 12 * 2**64 )+ 12" #221360928884514619404

Comment: $ perl -e ' use integer; $x = ( 3 * 2**63 )+ 12  ; print "$x\n" '
-9223372036854775796
$